# use slider to set transform:scale values in React function

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

In React, how can i set the translate:transform CSS parameters with a slider element? The slider can be anywhere on the page, it just has to set the size of the inner div *screenDiv*.

Currently, just have a react function that creates row and column list elements when dimensions are given and button toggled:

```
function DataFrame(){

  const [toggle, setToggle] = React.useState(false);
  const [col, setCol] = useState(0)
  const [row, setRow] = useState(0)
  var element = <li class="element"/>
  var arr = []
  var i
  for (i = 0; i<row; i++){
    arr.push(element)
  }

  const Element = () => <li className="element" />;

  return (

    <div>
      <div >
        <div >
          <p class="instructions3">
          <form class="codeForm">
            <label>
            row dim:
              <input type="number" name="dimension" onKeyUp=
              {e => setRow(Number(e.target.value))} />
              </label>
              <input class='goButton' type="submit" value="run" />
          </form></p>

          <p class="instructions3">
          <form class="codeForm">
            <label>
            column dim:
            <input type="number" name="dimension" onKeyUp=
            {e => setCol(Number(e.target.value))} />
            </label>
              <input class='goButton' type="submit" value="run" />
          </form>
          </p>

          </div>
          </div>

          <div class="btnConsole">
            <button class="dfButton" onClick={()=>setToggle( (prev) => (!prev) )}>
          </button>
          </div>
          </div>

          <div class="monitor"style={{}}>
          <div class="superScreen">
            <div class="screenDiv" >

              <div id="subScreen" class="subScreen" >
                {[...Array(col).keys()].map(ul => (
                  <ul key={ul}>
                    {toggle &&
                      [...Array(row).keys()].map(
                        li => <Element key={li} />)}
                  </ul>
                ))}

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default DF;
```

I want to put a slider in my React function, which the user can use to set the size of the inner div (screenDiv). currently, i just have scaling when hovered:

```
.screenDiv:active  {
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: scale(0.2,0.2)
}
```

additionally, an answer without using jQuery would be great, but not a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved with state and ref. Basic pattern could be:

```
const [sliderValue, setSliderValue] = useState(1); // scale value 1x
const ref = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
  ref.current.style.transform= `scaleX(${sliderValue})`;
}, [sliderValue]);

...

<input
  type="range"
  value={sliderValue}
  min={1}
  max={5}
  onChange={e => setSliderValue(e.target.value)}
/>
```

Attach `ref` to div/element you want to control.

[image: Edit slider controlled transform]

CSS

```
.screenDiv {
  transform-origin: top;
}
```

JSX

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [sliderValue, setSliderValue] = useState(1);
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(sliderValue);
    console.log(ref.current.style);
    ref.current.style.transform = `scale(${sliderValue})`;
  }, [sliderValue]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <input
        type="range"
        value={sliderValue}
        min={0.5}
        max={5}
        step={0.1}
        onChange={e => setSliderValue(e.target.value)}
      />

      <div ref={ref} className="screenDiv">
        Transform me!
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

***Also, be sure to use `className` in react instead of plain old `class`!***